# Reading CSV with Separator in column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a CSV saved as data.csv that looks like this, with two columns:

```
Column1|Column2
Titleone|1.5
Title|two|2.5
Title3|3.6
```

The third row of data in the CSV contains a pipe operator, | that is causing the error. I need a way to read in the pipe operator as part of the Column1 value for the third row. When I run `pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep = "|")` I get the error: `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3`

I cannot use, `on_bad_lines='skip'` since I'm on an old version of Pandas. This is a workaround I found that seems to be a partial solution:

```
col_names = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep = "|", names = col_names)
```

Comment: Your error looks like its coming from ```Title|two|2.5```. "Expected 2 fields, got 3" because it reads field1 = "Title", field2 = "two", field3 = 2.5.

Comment: why don't you read the data as a single column, and then do your split later -> `pd.read_csv(squeeze=True)`

Comment: Yes, third row in the csv or second row besides the header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`on_bad_lines` deprecates `error_bad_lines`, so if you're on an older version of `pandas`, you can just use that:

```
pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep = "|", error_bad_lines = False)
```

If you want to keep bad lines, you can also use `warn_bad_lines`, extract bad lines from the warnings and read them separately in a single column:

```
import contextlib

with open('log.txt', 'w') as log:
    with contextlib.redirect_stderr(log):
        df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep = '|', error_bad_lines = False, warn_bad_lines = True)

with open('log.txt') as f:
    f = f.readlines()

bad_lines = [int(x[0]) - 1 for x in f[0].split('line ')[1:]]

df_bad_lines = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows = lambda x: x not in bad_lines, squeeze = True, header = None)
```

Comment: This works, but I'd like to keep the row causing the error and retain the value "Title|two" in a single column value

Comment: Added an option to read bad lines separately